# How to add a script to boot/startup on Android?

Tags: android, executable, startup, boot

How can I make a script to run on startup or add an executable to the boot of the Android kernel?

Comment: You're asking a very big question. What is it you're trying to do? What kind of script? Do you mean like a bash script?

Comment: i want to start an sshd server on boot. it is an executable that i can start by issuing its name on a shell.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you do your own custom rom I guess the only thing you can use is creating a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and listen to `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`.